# How do I ignore/remove non-number values from linq query results C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have a linq query which iterates over hundreds of XML elements to count the quantity of specific tools used in a collection of tools.

However, the qty element in the tools xelement collection, which should contain a number, occasionally contains text such as "As required" as opposed to a specific number. This clearly causes problems.

Is there a simple additional step i can put into this linq query (i'm not good with linq) that will either ignore non-number values, or filter them out?

Linq query is:

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = listTools.Descendants("tool")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Element("id"), y => (int)y.Element("qty"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Sum());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `int.TryParse`:

```
.GroupBy(x => (int)x.Element("id"), 
         y => int.TryParse(y.Element("qty"), out int qty) ? qty : 0)
```

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__):

> The conversion fails if the s parameter is null or Empty, is not of the correct format, or represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue

Try this:

```
.GroupBy(x => (int)x.Element("id"), 
         y => 
         {
             int qty = 0;
             if (int.TryParse(y.Element("qty"), out qty))
                 return qty;
             return 0;
         })
```

Comment: Thanks Ric, but I'm getting an issue on the 'out int qty' part, and the 'qty' that follows it (invalid expression term int, and qty does not exist in the current context, respectively). Any ideas please?

Comment: sure, you may not have the latest .net framework, try my suggestion

Comment: This gives me a 'cannot convert from XElement to string' error on this part: y.Element("qty").
Sorry to be a pain but i'm yet to learn and fully understand lamdas and linq so i'm flying blind on this.

Comment: `y.Element("qty").Value` ?

Comment: Yes, on this line of your example: if (int.TryParse(y.Element("qty"), out qty))

Comment: Update your code to either y.Element("qty").Value or y.Element("qty").ToString()

Comment: The problem 'cannot convert from XElement to string' you have is that the TryParse accept as first parameter a string so you need to convert y.Element("qty") to a string first then the method will convert the value into an integer

Comment: The simpler method is to define the integer as int? (put a question mark at the end) which will allow nulls.  The key cannot be a null, but the "y" value can be null.